# Loop for each group of variables in php

Tags: php, loops

i have a form with multiple inputs and hidden fields.

query example when form submited:

> cart.php?prdcode1=102334&qty1=3&prdcode2=247104&qty2=1&prdcode3=220349&qty3=3
>
> ... and so on...

i have this code in classic ASP that creates a LOOP for each of my record

```
For i = 0 To cINT(request("number_of_records"))
if (Request("qty"&i)) then

sqlquery="UPDATE cart SET qty='"&Request("qty"&i)&"' WHERE prdcode='"&Request("prdcode"&i)&"' AND sessionid='"&sesid&"'"
Con.Execute sqlquery

end if
next
```

can anybody help me to translate this to PHP?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<$_GET['number_of_records']; $i++) {
    if(isset($_GET['qty'.$i])) {
        $sqlQuery = "UPDATE cart SET qty='" . $_GET['qty'.$i] . "' WHERE prdcode='" . $_GET['prdcode'.$i] . "' AND sessionid='" . session_id() . "'";

        $db->query($sqlQuery);
    }
}
```

`$db` being your your `mysqli` database connection. (Check [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) if you don't know how to initialize a connection to a database in PHP)